# Facebook conversion API CAPI

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-ads-api

Could someone tell me how I can get the server side events? I only have simple html pages that I would like to get the events but I only get it from the browser but I need to get it from the server? How can I install to receive via server?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean? CAPI is meant for FB to receive the events happening on your website, sent via the backend not the other way around.

Comment: Yes is this. But i add code in html,  and received  return just of browser, and not of server, image::: https://i.imgur.com/yj8ShBh.png  just of browser and server not work. I need just of server. And my site is in html. I using the code normal. You can help me?

Comment: @BarbaraEster any update on that. how do you handle that issue?